# Touchpad not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, touchpad

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 from Windows Vista (Wubi) and use it as a dual boot. However while in the process of installing I turned the touch pad off. And after installation the touchpad is not working.

I am using the dual boot in a Compaq CQ40 317-TU laptop.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's a nice graphical tool that alows you to simply enable and disable the touchpad. You can install it by typing on a console:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator`

[Official page](https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator)

1. You can try to enable it from the System Settings
2. You can try running from the console
   `synclient TouchpadOff=0`

   1. sudo gedit /etc/rc.local 
      Before the line exit 0 you will add the following lines:

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse`

`sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

Save the file and reboot the computer

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970535)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install touchpad-indicator and synaptic.  Those are needed packages to touchpad.

Comment: Do you mean "install touchpad-indicator with synaptic?  Either way your answer is incomplete.  What does the OP do after installation as suggested to resolve the issue.

Comment: i was in mobile .

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add more detail. This would make it more useful, should anyone else have the same problem.