# Mousepad not working with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, 64-bit, touchpad, 32-bit

I am running 12.04 64-bit, and I have had a bit of trouble with Ubuntu. First, I installed 12.10 32-bit, and then I tried to install 64-bit, but it didn't work. Then, one of my friends, who has the exact same computer as I do, said that he installed 12.04 LTS 64-bit, and it ran perfectly. So I tried doing that, and then upgrading to 12.10 from the terminal, however that didn't work either. Then I decided to run 12.04, because it was 64-bit, but once I installed it, I had to update a couple of things (85 to be exact) and I also updated a driver. I rebooted my computer, because you have to do that after you update something, and then the mousepad stopped working. I can click the buttons, but I can't move it. When I was running Windows 7, and when I was running 12.10 32-bit, it worked fine, and I don't know what to do. It has to be said, that I am a complete Ubuntu Novice, and I don't really know what to do.

Here are my specs:
 - Packard Bell Easynote LM series
 - 640 GB HDD
 - 6 GB DDR3 Ram
 - AMD Phenom II X2 N660

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following link
[Mouse/Touchpad stuck in Ubuntu 12.04](https://superuser.com/a/437607/140285)

[Touchpad not work in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/190491/67654)

[Laptop Touchpad Not Working in Ubuntu 11.10](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/11/is-your-laptop-touchpad-not-working.html)