# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Toshiba touchpad not working

Tags: mouse, laptop, touchpad, synaptics, toshiba

I have a Toshiba Satellite T130-10G laptop and I can't get my touchpad to work in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (I have tried also 12.10 and did not work either).

In the same laptop I have Windows 7 installed and the touchpad works 100% so I know it isn't hardware failure.

I've also already installed 2 different softwares to check if touchpad is enabled, and it is on both (I don't recall the names but I found them in similar problems here).
If I go to System Settings and select Mouse and Touchpad I have both tabs there.
Also, if I plug an USB mouse it works 100% but the touchpad remains dead...

I do have a <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> shortcut to enable/disable touchpad in Windows 7 (which works correctly) but does nothing in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Please help me... I don't know what else to do...

Comment: I've updated my ubuntu to 13.04 and I still have the same problem.
Please help me, it's a laptop and the touchpad is kinda crucial...

Answer (score 1):

Had problem with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Toshiba Satellite L50 B. Lost 2 days and accidentally found a solution.

Reinstalling OS(Ubuntu) does not help !!!

Problem cause:

- First I pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> - go to sleep mode.
- After that I accidentaly pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> - disable touchpad, can happen easily because <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd> are next to each other (thanks Toshiba :))

When I go to normal mode and press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, touchpad remains disabled !!!!

So a fix is:

- Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> - go to sleep mode
- Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> - enable touchpad
- Press <kbd>Power button</kbd> - go to normal mode

Good luck!

Comment: Same problem with the S50, and same solution, thanks! I have the same issue since upgrading to Windows 10, so will try the same thing when I next boot into that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270336/mousepad-not-working-with-12-04)

Just look at the first answer.

I know it isn't dualboot, but it worked for me, when i was running 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same problem, but at last I figured it out.

Restart your laptop and while restarting press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter into BIOS and press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in order to refresh the hardware settings (although you cant see the BIOS getting refreshed). Thats it and now just save and exit from BIOS and your touchpad starts working.