# touchpad Detected but not working in Ubuntu 14.04 on toshiba satellite p75 a7200

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, synaptics

I have a toshiba satalite that I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on and it runs great. But the touchpad does not work. I plugged in a usb mouse and it worked fine but the laptop touchpad wont work. I tried everything I could find under the sun and it is detected and all and says its enabled but does not work. I have pressed fn f7 to enable the mouse and still nothing. Synaptics is installed im pretty sure to because I used synaptics --list or something like that and It worked fine.

Comment: Maybe you could try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/648465/242730 It helped me with Toshiba satellite L50 B.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Toshiba Satellite, as well & I'm facint the same problem. I'm still searching for a real solution, but there is a possible way to handle this bug - in case, you have windows on your laptop, too. My experience is: if I enable touchpad during windows workflow (Fn+F9 here), then it works (after reboot) in Ubuntu, as well; but if I disable it in windows, I can't enable it in Ubuntu... Horrible! :)

Comment: could anyone confirm this?

Comment: With a dual boot windows/Ubuntu14.04 on Toshiba Satellite L855 also, it works like described above for me

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Bios > Advanced > System Configurations > Internal Pointing Device = Enable

That should do it.